# Complicated Wi-Fi Question

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, busybox

So every time that I enable and re-enable the wifi connection on my tablet, the MAC address is randomized (like the last 3-4 digits).  I don't know what might be causing this, and the root account can't seem to disable the internet connection since it's constantly restarted by whatever daemon is running the wifi service.  However, when the daemon restarts the service, the MAC address is not randomized.  I have tested the following via the busybox program and it hasn't worked:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing

I need to do this since my campus wifi only allows through devices with consistent information since we have to pay to use the wifi here each semester.

Answer (score 0):

easy route download an app for that there are apps that will do this for you

or

you  should be able to add static macaddress in the following directory  if rooted , use a root explorer of your choice , and goto

/efs/wifi

theres two files  .mac.cob  and .mac.info

if you edit both of them files , input the macaddress you need to have and save files , now
they should presist across reboots.

worst case senario add init.d support and make a script to run at 
boot

example: file in /etc/init.d       file = 0Amacaddress.sh

#

#!/system/bin/sh

echo 00:00:00:00:00:00 > /efs/.mac.cob

echo 00:00:00:00:00:00 > /efs/.mac.info

#

00:00:00:00:00:00 is an example , use the macaddress you need to have

and your script if you go that route , will need proper permissions to execute at boot

Comment: I've tried some of the applications available in the play store, but they haven't worked.  Also, I don't have these files under "/".

Comment: im new to this type of edit my device has /efs  "efs" folder with the two file i mentioned , , if yours does not , my knowledge goes no further , sorry good luck